# How to solve "Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)" error in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, environment-variables, create-react-app, api-key

I have a very frustrating error involving the use of API key with Firebase Authentication.

```
Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
```

I'm using environment variables to avoid from hardcoding my API key into my config files.

Tried a lot of things: making sure I copied the API keys correctly, restarting my dev server, verifying identity using the `firebase-admin` npm module etc. etc.

### ./src/config/firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_APP_ID
});

export const auth = app.auth();
export const database = firebase.firestore();
export default app;
```

### .env.local

```
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_API_KEY=xxx
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=xxx
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=xxx
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=xxx
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=xxx
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=xxx
QUIZZI_FIREBASE_APP_ID=xxx
```

I also referred to [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/61) but none of the solutions are working for me.

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the thread [mentioned](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/61) deeper, I found out it was because of the naming convention for create-react-app for environment variables.

I'm supposed to use `REACT_APP_*` to name any env variables for security reasons.

Credit to [this article](https://adostes.medium.com/using-environment-variables-in-a-react-application-ac3b6c307373).

Refer to [the official docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem `"process.env.QUIZZI_FIREBASE_API_KEY",`....try having the variable between "...."

Comment: Consider using the same base code as the question

Comment: Ouw, great...thanks. I'll do that next time. I'm new here.